# Custom options by default

Tags: custom-options

Is it possible for each product to make two of custom options so that when you create a product in the tab of Custom option, these two options are the default.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not looking for free solution you can use following extension,
   http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html

It provide you to create custom option template that can be assigned to all or selected products.

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box.

1. Either you implement some JS to do this when you open the create product area
2. or you add an observer for catalog_product_before_save which adds the custom option later. You can base it on an attribute or add another field (with a second observer) to the product form with no linked attribute to define this option should be added or not, so you don't have to delete it after saving